# Re-request on state change react

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to make my component make a new request when state changes in react. I believe that i understand the lifecycle methods, but i cannot manage to make my component make a new request when the date state changes.

I have used componentWillUpdate with prevState, where prevState returns the updated state instead of the previous date.

Anything that can help me in the right direction is appriciated.

```
this.state = {
   date: moment(),
   bookings: []
}

componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // prevState returns updated state
}

componentWillMount() {
   const { course } = this.props.match.params;
   const payload = {
     startDate: this.state.date.format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
     endDate: this.state.date.add(1, 'd').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
   }

   axios.get(`/api/booking/find/${course}? startDate=${payload.startDate}&endDate=${payload.endDate}`).then(response => {
      this.setState({
         bookings: response.data
      })
   });
}



  onNext = () => {
    this.setState({
      date: this.state.date.add(1, 'd')
    })
  }

  onPrev = () => {
    this.setState({
      date: this.state.date.subtract(1, 'd')
    })
  }
```

Comment: Use componentDidUpdate instead, and this should solve your issue. Also, use componentDidMount instead.

Comment: That solution does not worker either :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.state.date.isSame(prevState.date)) {
    // do request
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work either, prevState.date and this.state.date are the exact same, and i cant figure out why

Comment: @patrickn just noticed you are using `moment`, you'll probably find that moment doesn't give you back a new instance when you make a change. Therefore you'll need to use the many utility functions to determine the date has changed instead e.g. `if (!this.state.date.isSame(prevState.date)) { ... }`. Alternatively, you could always create new instances when you set the date `date: moment(this.state.date.add(1, 'd'))`

Comment: ...or migrate to luxon if codebase is rather small. it does not mutate date variable for any operation afaik

Answer (score 0):

According to [React doc](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate), `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate` will soon be deprecated.

Btw, this function signature is `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`, this is why you get the updated state.

You should consider extracting your axios get request inside a function, that could be called inside a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method :

```
this.state = {
   date: moment(),
   bookings: []
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.date.valueOf() !== prevState.date.valueOf()) {
        this.getBookings();
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getBookings();
}

getBookings = () => {
    const { course } = this.props.match.params;
    const payload = {
        startDate: this.state.date.format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
        endDate: this.state.date.add(1, 'd').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
    }


    axios.get(`/api/booking/find/${course}? startDate=${payload.startDate}&endDate=${payload.endDate}`).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            bookings: response.data
        })
    });
}

onNext = () => {
    this.setState({
        date: this.state.date.add(1, 'd')
    })
}

onPrev = () => {
    this.setState({
        date: this.state.date.subtract(1, 'd')
    })
}
```